# Non responsive HMD sensors in Blend4Web CE

Tags: blend4web, webgl

I am developing a simple VR app to my Galaxy Nexus 5 using Chrome/59.0.3071.125 via blend4web CE 17.06. The app responds perfectly to any rotation movement, so I can look around, this is provided out of the  box by the blend4web SDK.
However when I try to access the HMD position or quat data I get the same static values:
pos = [1, 1, 1]
quat = [0, 0, 0, 1]

Regardless of the position of my phone.

Here is the code snippet I use to access the data:

```
function register_hmd() {
                m_hmd_conf.update();
                // camera rotation is enabled with HMD
                m_hmd.enable_hmd(m_hmd.HMD_ALL_AXES_MOUSE_NONE);

                var cam = m_scenes.get_active_camera();
                var position = m_ctl.create_hmd_position_sensor();
                var rotation = m_ctl.create_hmd_quat_sensor();

                function gesture_detect_cb(obj, id, pulse) {
                        var pos = m_ctl.get_sensor_payload(obj, id, 0);
                        var quat = m_ctl.get_sensor_payload(obj, id, 1);
                        console.log("pos", pos[0], pos[1], pos[2],
                                                "quat", quat[0], quat[1], quat[2], quat[3]);
                        console.log(m_hmd.get_pos);
                }
```

Comment: I'm not sure about your problem specifically, but... have you tried asking on the b4w forum? As great as SE is, sometimes the b4w forum can be a better resource, as the devs will often quickly respond with helpful answers, and they know about Blend4Web better than anyone.

Comment: Agreed, you better ask on the B4W forums